Raid 5 replace with read errors
I have a software RAID 5 with 3 disks.
For a few days, sda has been giving errors, and today the new disk arrived.
I launched mdadm --replace and the process started correctly, but due to read errors on the disk, the operation is taking a very long time (over a week for about 1TB).
Should I be patient, or can I use --remove sda? And force the recovery using parity information instead?
What do you recommend?

please share cat /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min and cat /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_max there is also a chance using Bitmap option but some suggest them some not

The rebuild had problems all night due to errors, so much so that I was on the verge of stopping it several times.
But it seems we have finished copying the damaged part of the disk, and now it is proceeding very well (130 MB/s)

since you basically hide mandatory information, it's hard to help you.

I didn't post the speed limits because they were not related to the problem.
cat /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min 1000  cat /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_max 150000
